# How to scale x axis values on svg chart?

Tags: html, css, svg, scaling

I have a line chart (no library). I need to scale value on X axis only depends on screen with.

This is my chart

```
<svg width="100%" height="300">
    <rect x="40" y="280" width="100%" height="1" fill="#E6E6E6"></rect>
    <rect x="40" y="0" width="1" height="280" fill="#E6E6E6"></rect>

    <g>
        <path
            d="
                M70,250
                L120,220
                L170,200
                L220,160
                "
            stroke="#FE5131" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

How to scale  with css? I mean L120, become L150... on wider screens and so on.

Comment: add a viewBox to the root element.

Comment: it scales Y axis too.

Comment: Then add preserveAspectRatio="none"

Comment: But how can I determine 2 last values for viewBox? (viewBox="0 0 ? ?") It's responsive screen. Any gues?

Comment: 220 maybe. Feel free to experiment.